# Usb WiFi dongle pluggin in doesnt create wlan0 interface

Tags: wireless

I use **D-Link DWA-110** WiFi usb dongle. It used to be working well, but after some config changes I broke something and now when I plug the dongle in I see it in lsusb output, but wlan0 isn't created and the led on the dongle doesn't light.

What to check out?

```
~ > uname -a
Linux Distress 3.2.0-56-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 17:31:43 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

dmesg shows

```
[  667.824095] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[  668.117996] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=07d1, idProduct=3c07
[  668.118007] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  668.118015] usb 1-8: Product: 802.11 bg WLAN
[  668.118021] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: Ralink
```

Comment: try `lspci` command,there you find your wireless interface.

Comment: Nope, I see my device in lsusb output but ifconfig shows no **wlan0**, but only **lo** and **eth0**

Comment: updating the kernal will may help.

Comment: Updated, but didn't help

    Linux Distress 3.8.0-33-generic #48~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 24 16:31:16 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that previously I removed windows driver for the dongle, but missed these pieces of ndiswrapper configuration:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/ndiswrapper.conf
alias usb:v07D1p3C03d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip* ndiswrapper
alias usb:v07D1p3C04d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip* ndiswrapper
alias usb:v07D1p3C07d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip* ndiswrapper
```

which directly aliases my dongle to ndiswrapper (which stopped working due to I purged windows driver)

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
# for dlink dwa-110
blacklist rt73usb
blacklist rt2x00usb
blacklist rt2x00lib
# blacklist ndiswrapper
```

which directly denies using linux native drivers

The interface appeared after I commented out these directives